# c# Runtime Assembly Load, ByRef Method Invoke

Tags: c#, performance, assemblies, runtime

I am loading assemblies at runtime and calling methods on a particular class. I have a List (on hosting application) that I want to access from the runtime loaded assembly and the only way I can think of doing so is to pass the list in as a paramter, would that have a huge performance impact and is there perhaps any other option other than passing the List as a parameter?

Thanks
Q

Comment: what is the big performance impact you think there is?

Comment: I thought it might send the referenced parameter into a new appdomain (where the assembly was loaded) as cross appdomain calls will have some overhead or use some form of marshalling, wasn't sure which it would implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing a List in means passing a reference - this has no performance impact.

Comment: Thanks, thought that the cross appdomain factor would have a performance impact, but I could just host the assembly into the current appdomain for that.